# How to make render still remained after reload?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-router

The problem that I'm facing now is, there's a profile tab which shows some information on itself. I typed interface solutions like "input". After I save its value to data(data that placed on another component, especially contained in this.state). Then I shifted to component which renders its interface. In detail, I mentioned its value to which to show. Soooooo, I can't understand that how to still show it after reload? I hope it pulls something from back-end or axios or git things. Briefly, "how to maintain the data on the profile tab after reload? I'm in react js stuff.

Comment: React by itself cannot fundamentally retain any form of state beyond its initial instantiation. A reload destroys that instance. Your two options are to have a server that tracks this information or to place the data in localStorage

Answer (score 0):

React state is just a variable which stores data. When you refresh your browser, the browser clears its value from memory and reinitilizes that variable.

To get back that data, you have to store that data somewhere which persists even after browser refreshes like

1. You can use session Storage or local storage.
   https://javascript.info/localstorage
2. You can user server to store your data and use axios to fetch data using useEffect hook.
3. You can also use the npm package redux-persist or react-persist https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-persist

Comment: please, can you explain about second option?

Comment: That means store your data in a database. 

Then you can fetch that data using axios or fetch in useEffect function.

Comment: Well, I dont have much knowledge on backend. But you can read about it in detail here:

https://blog.logrocket.com/mern-stack-a-to-z-part-1/

Comment: Also, this link is best to get familiar about database:

https://illustrated.dev/databases

Comment: In summary, you have to  keep a database on a server. You can store your data there and setup api urls for CRUD (CREATE, READ, UPDATE, DELETE) operations with your data.

These api urls are called by axios/fetch library on front end. These api calls return some data. So, when you refresh your page, you can call an api (made for READ operation) in useEffect function, which returns data that you can keep in state.